# Сортировка массива по количеству значений одного из элементов

Tags: массивы, php, sortable

Есть массив:

```
$routes[] = array('numbler' => '324', 'type' => '1', 'elements' => array(1,2,3)); // А
$routes[] = array('numbler' => '311', 'type' => '2', 'elements' => array(4)); // В
$routes[] = array('numbler' => '376', 'type' => '2', 'elements' => array(5,6)); // С
```

Необходимо отсортировать его по возрастанию количества элементов в "подмассиве" `elements`. То есть, в итоге, они должны быть в таком порядке: В, С, А.

Подскажите, как лучше всего такое реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function mySort($f1, $f2) {
    return (count($f1['elements']) < count($f2['elements'])) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($routes, 'mySort');
print_r($routes);
```